# Bad request error when sending PHP SOAP request but request itself correct

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I've been stuck on this problem for ages now and have been unable to find a solution after *many many* hours of searching.

I'm using a Fedex web-service that returns a shipping rate. The following is my php code

```
try { 

    $client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array(
                     'uri' => 'http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14',
                     'location' => 'https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate',
                     'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',
                     'login' => 'myusername',       //I don't know whether this is needed but but it is an internal company site 
                     'password' => 'password',      //so I log in with this username and pw to see it
                     'proxy_host' => 'proxy-host-name',
                     'proxy_port' => 443,
                     'proxy_login'    => '',
                     'proxy_password' => '',
                     'trace' => 1,
                     'exceptions' => 1));

    $data = array(
        'Action' => "http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14/getRates"
    );
    $header = new SoapHeader('http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14', 'FedexHeader', $data, false);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')){
        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
    }
    $response = $client -> getRates($request);
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo '<h2>exception</h2>';
    print_r($exception); 
    echo '<br/><h2>exception trace</h2>';
    var_dump($exception->getTraceAsString());

    echo '<br/>Request headers : <br/><xmp>', 
        $client->__getLastRequestHeaders(), 
        '</xmp><br/>';
    echo 'Request : <br/><xmp>', 
        $client->__getLastRequest(), 
        '</xmp><br/>';
    echo 'Response headers: <br/><xmp>', 
        $client->__getLastResponseHeaders(), 
        '</xmp><br/>';
    echo 'Response : <br/><xmp>', 
        $client->__getLastResponse(), 
        '</xmp><br/>';               
        printFault($exception, $client);        
}
```

This is actually sample code from Fedex - the only parts I have changed are the pathname to the wsdl file, adding more debug information and setting the SoapHeader.

The following is the Request Header:

```
POST /web-services/rate HTTP/1.1 Host: ws.fedex.com 
Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.27 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 
SOAPAction: "http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14/getRates" 
Content-Length: 2974
```

and the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
Date: Mon, 17 Feb 2014 16:25:56 
GMT Server: Apache/2.2 
Content-Length: 226 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Here is part of the SOAP request itself that is generated:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <ns2:Action>http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14/getRates</ns2:Action>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>

    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:RateRequest>
         <ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ns1:UserCredential>
               //user credentials
            </ns1:UserCredential>
         </ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
         <ns1:ClientDetail>
           //client details
         </ns1:ClientDetail>
         <ns1:RequestedShipment>
            //shipping details ..
         </ns1:RequestedShipment>
      </ns1:RateRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The thing is that when I paste this request into SOAP UI it returns the correct response. Also the Fedex support team have confirmed that it is correct.

This is why I think it has to be an error with the PHP. (I was getting a Could not connect to Host error for a long time - I believe it was related to the proxy host but our ops team have confirmed that this request is hitting the proxy now so I think this is resolved)

I saw references to setting SoapHeader in a few other posts so I have done this - however I'm not sure if I am using the correct namespace. Also I'm wondering if I should be using soapAction instead of Action as the wsdl refers to soapAction? Here is that part from the wsdl file:

```
<operation name="getRates">
  <s1:operation soapAction="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14/getRates" style="document"/>
</operation>
```

However, I have tried using both and it didn't make a difference. Also this request works in SoapUI without having the soap header..

UPDATE: I did think originally that it might be related to SSL Speaking to Fedex support it seems I do not need to use SSL.

The fact that the request works in SoapUI does make me think it has to be something in the code.

Any tips on how I could debug this more or suggestions on what the issue could be would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have updated the code to include some new parameters in the SoapClient constructor. My main question at this point is the SSL issue - could this be causing the problem? But if so, why does the request work in SoapUI. I have been reading up on it and OpenSSL is installed on the host but I don't have the cert or passphrase info. Before I go down the road of trying to set up certs I'd like to know if its necessary at this point? Any info on that or on what could be causing the Bad Request error would be fantastic..

Comment: I have asked Fedex support about SSL and they said "I am not aware of needing to supply SSL details within the transaction itself, no. I have personally not had to do so when running XML or Soap/XML transactions via SoapUI." 

So now I am inclined to think that just because our site uses SSL, it doesn't mean we need to have SSL authentication to access the Fedex web service.. So something else is causing the problem.

Comment: So a colleague has run this code on a different server and it works perfectly. So the PHP code itself is probably fine.

So maybe this means there is some difference in the way the server is configured - does anyone know what that could be?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We were given a .cer file with the api docs and instructions to install it in the browser, I dont know how this fits into the bigger picture and php